# centos 7 shell script is running but not filling mysql table php

Tags: php, bash, shell, centos, codeigniter-4

I am on centos 7 and created a xyz.service , this xyz.service call a my.sh , my.sh run spark command Codeigniter 4, if i see next day serivce is running but no data saved in table. i mean i have to stop service and then start service then all working fine but xyz service is running as when i checked the status on terminal so why it is not working as automated? is there any ?

```
 [Unit]
 Description=My service xyz
 [Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/mysite/public_html/ltsh/my.sh
 Restart=on-failure
 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
 Alias=my.service


#!/bin/bash
echo $$ >> f1
while :; do
   cd /home/mysite/public_html/; /usr/local/bin/php spark myspark
done &
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? As you haven't shared any of the PHP code, it's impossible to tell why it does not work

Comment: maybe you want a cron job and not a service.

Comment: What happens instead? Aren't there any error messages produced? Did you try to run your script with `set -x`, to see what is actually executed?

Comment: i am connecting my service with my.sh and my.sh shell script will continuous call command spark Using CLI codeigniter 4because as per requirement 5 seconds data needed , i did not use cron. as you can see i started my service so each day like monday , next day data should be automatically save to tables but on 3 day i have to stop my servie and then start it on teminal then data is saving to table.
why it is not saving data to table if service is running and calling my.sh command?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it